# [[ ]] что это такое в MAP?

Tags: javascript

Что означают двоенные скобки типа: [["cucumber", 400]] в MAP?

Пример:

```js
let recipeMap = new Map([["cucumber", 400]]); // Зачем нужны **[[ ]]** ?
```

Comment: для создания объекта, в котором будут созданы еще объекты
let recipeMap = new Map([["cucumber", 400], ['tomato', 800]]); //например

Comment: При создании объектов же используют фигурные скобки { } ?

Comment: Это не сдвоенные скобки. Это массив внутри массива.

Comment: А человек сверху сказал, что это объект. Так это объект или массив?

Comment: @Человек человек сверху ошибся. Это массивы.

Answer (score 1):

Ну а что тут непонятного? Такой синтаксис. Конструктор `Map` жрёт  информацию только двумерными массивами.

```js
map = new Map([
  ['key1','value1'],
  ['key2','value2'],
  ['key3','value3'],
  ['key4','value4'],
  ['key5','value5'],
  ['key6','value6'],
]);  

console.log(Object.fromEntries(map.entries()));
```

Comment: [ [ ] ] - это массив внутри другого массива? А человек сверху сказал, что это объект.

Comment: @Человек Все массивы - это объекты [JS.Garden](https://shamansir.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/ru/).